# Iterating over Dictionary with foreach, in what order is this done?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary

Say I have a `Dictionary`, and I add each `key` and `value` entry in a specific order.
Now, if I want later to be able to iterate this `Dictionary` in the same order entries were added, is it the order I get with simple `foreach` loop on this dictionary?

If not, I will be glad to hear how can I do that, I know this can be done easily with `List` instead of `Dictionary` but I don't want to.

Thanks

Comment: No, Dictionary does not maintain order.  Unfortunately, I think you need to use a List.

Comment: use a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V> >` instead (e.g. a List<>)

Comment: @sehe Dictionary *is* an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>`.

Comment: @phoog You might find I know that. The point is, it's not the same. Also: It **is** not, it **implements**

Comment: @sehe I'm sure you do know that.  My point is, you can't just "use an IEnumerable... instead."  Rather, you have to choose a concrete class that implements the interface, and the question at hand is what class to use.

Comment: @phoog I don't know _why_ you keep insisting on ignoring the rest of my comment, but something tells me you will. So I call it a day. you know, the beauty of SO is that _your_ preferred comment style can complement that of others (me). No need to catch flies.

Comment: @sehe, because I didn't *see* the rest of your comment; did you edit the comment, perhaps?  Still, saying "use `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` instead of `Dictionary<K, V>` is rather like saying "use a tool instead of a hammer".

Comment: Is the insert order important, or could you order simply by comparing the items after they're inserted?  If the latter, use a `SortedDictionary`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Normal `Dictionary` does not guarantee order of items.

You need [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=VS.80).aspx) if you want to maintain order items where added to it. Note that there is no generic version of this class in .Net framework, so either have to give up some type-safety or find other implementation (i.e. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18615/OrderedDictionary-T-A-generic-implementation-of-IO as [suggested by Tim S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998185/iterating-over-dictionary-with-foreach-in-what-order-is-this-done/13998263#comment19323194_13998263)).

Alternatively if O(log n) lookup is fine and keys should be sorted - [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Note that this class does not use generics, and so it is not type-safe.  If you'd like your collection to use generics (I'd recommend it), use something like this implementation of `OrderedDictionary`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18615/OrderedDictionary-T-A-generic-implementation-of-IO

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like what you want is a `Queue<T>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

Add your `KeyValuePair<T, U>` items to it in the order you want and then `foreach`ing over it will be in first-in/first-out order.

Comment: Well, this could also be accomplished with a `List<T>`, so a `Queue<T>` is not really necessary here.

Answer (score 3):

`Dictionary`s are hash tables, which means that you can't guarantee that iterating the pairs will return them in the same order you added them.

Each pair is a `KeyValuePair<T_K, T_V>`, so you could have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` that would let you iterate in the order you add them if that's what you need.

Comment: Can you please explain more about `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`,guess  you didn't mean to list of dictionaries don't you?

Comment: @JavaSa When you enumerate `Dictionary` you get an enumeration of `KeyValuePair<T,K>`s, so I was just using a list.  Alexei Levenkov's answer is definitely more correct though

Answer (score 2):

The internal sort of the dictionary will depend on the hash function used. However if you need a sorted view of the data, you can use `Enumerable.OrderBy`.