# Does C# have an equivalent to the Java LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry

Tags: .net, linkedhashmap, lru

Java has a really useful feature in LinkedHashMap. A member function [removeEldestEntry()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry-java.util.Map.Entry-) where you can return true when the hash is over N entries. Great way to easily declare a LRU cache.

Is there anything like this in .NET?

Edit: [The question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205934/c-sharp-equivalent-of-linkedhashmap) does not answer this as that solution does not provide the functionality in removeEldestEntry().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# equivalent of LinkedHashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205934/c-sharp-equivalent-of-linkedhashmap)

Comment: @cemal - that solution does not have the functionality removeEldestEntry().

Comment: What about creating your <key,value> pairs and adding them into a queue as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13998338/4606005

Comment: @cemal yes I can put them in both a queue and a hashmap. I was hoping to avoid having two collections. Also, with this solition, each time an item is accessed in the hashmap, it has to be moved in the queue. That's expensive.

Comment: Which are you actually wanting to find the equivalent, a true/false stating if the eldest entry should be removed or the action of removing the eldest entry based on the result of that check? If you are wanting LRU cache behavior, just use the [`MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class, you can configure it to evict LRU entries.