# C# equivalent of LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, c#, collections

As the question says, I'm looking for the c# equivalent of the **LinkedHashMap** in Java.

I need to be able to retrieve keys *and* values by index, get the size. I need the elements to be ordered in the way they are inserted. One key should be matched to exactly one value.

Collections I've tried (And problems with them):
**NameValueCollection** - Allows one-many linking. I'm guessing this causes an unnecessary overhead.
**OrderedDictionary** - Unable to retrieve key by index.

**EDIT** : It has been pointed out that no such equivalent exists in C#. In the linked question, the answer points to a forum for an example implementation, which appears to be down. Could someone perhaps provide an example implementation here?

**EDIT 2** : A **CookieCollection** from System.Net appears to be what I need. How would this react to larger sizes (number of elements)?

Comment: No. The OP asks desires a particular feature of LinkedHashMaps when he asks "the elements are (re)ordered automatically". Jok Skeet then proceeds to mention that feature is available only in a particular constructor. I on the other hand, desire a wholesome equivalent of it.

Comment: Read asnwers carfeully: Your question: "I'm looking for the c# equivalent of the LinkedHashMap in Java.". Answer (that can be found in linked thread): "there is no built in C# equivalent for LinkedHashMap".

Comment: If `NameValueCollection` works fine, but you are "guessing" that there is "unnecessary overhead", then the chances that you would notice the overhead are stacked heavily against you.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Perhaps you're right. But considering that I use it in various cases in my programming, I'd like it to be efficient. Also, I expect heavy use of the collection, with sizes beyond 10k.

Comment: @Hele Any talks of efficiency would be premature without profiling. If you are not satisfied with efficiency of the implementation, you can always port Java's code, or write your own.

Comment: @Hele Any talks of efficiency would be premature without profiling. If you are not satisfied with efficiency of the implementation, you can always port Java's code, or write your own.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Just out of the blue, a CookieCollection from System.Net seems to be perfect. Opinion?

Comment: @Hele "Unable to retrieve key by index." Do you numerical index?  If so, isn't the Keys collection ordered as well?

Comment: LinkedHashMap can be used for multiple things one of which is LRU cache. Here's what I came up with: http://bashtavenko.com/lru-cache-without-linkedhashmap/

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this one, worked well enough for me in the past. Let me know if you find a mistake.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class LinkedHashMap<T, U>
{
    Dictionary<T, LinkedListNode<Tuple<U, T>>> D = new Dictionary<T, LinkedListNode<Tuple<U, T>>>();
    LinkedList<Tuple<U,T>> LL = new LinkedList<Tuple<U, T>>();

    public U this[T c]
    {
        get
        {
            return D[c].Value.Item1;
        }

        set
        {
            if(D.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                LL.Remove(D[c]);
            }

            D[c] = new LinkedListNode<Tuple<U, T>>(Tuple.Create(value, c));
            LL.AddLast(D[c]);
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(T k)
    {
        return D.ContainsKey(k);
    }

    public U PopFirst()
    {
        var node = LL.First;
        LL.Remove(node);
        D.Remove(node.Value.Item2);
        return node.Value.Item1;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return D.Count;
        }
    }
}

class LinkedHashMapTest 
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var lhm = new LinkedHashMap<char, int>();

        lhm['a'] = 1;
        lhm['b'] = 2;
        lhm['c'] = 3;


        Console.WriteLine(lhm['a']);
        Console.WriteLine(lhm['b']);
        Console.WriteLine(lhm['c']);

        Console.WriteLine(lhm.PopFirst());
        Console.WriteLine(lhm.PopFirst());
        Console.WriteLine(lhm.PopFirst());
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you iterate over the elements in the dictionary/linked list?  As I understand it the advantage of a LinkedHashMap is that it's like a Dictionary with a predictable iteration order.  So I assume being able to iterate over the elements would be important.

Comment: You can just expose an iterator over LL (`LinkedList<Tuple<U,T>> LL`).