# checking each char in string is outputted in wrong order?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, dictionary

im trying to split a string into a chars(which i have semi done) and use each char to compare it to my dictionary full of random strings, and then add that chars value in the dictionary to a finished string. the problem is what its outputting- the chars are not in order.

**ex: USER INPUT: "hello"---**

**ex: CONSOLE: "e"-"l"-"l"-"o"-"h"**

thats what happens mostly. any answer as to how i can get it to spell it correctly in the console?

Code:

```
private void complete_text_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    end_result = input_box.Text.ToString();
    string end_translated_result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ZENOX_LANGUAGE.Keys.Count; i ++)
    {

        foreach (char iq in end_result.ToCharArray())
        {
            
            
            if (iq.ToString().ToLower() == ZENOX_LANGUAGE.Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString().ToLower())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(iq);
                end_translated_result += ZENOX_LANGUAGE.Values.ElementAt(i) + " ";
                
                //Console.WriteLine("sender: " + sender.ToString() + " c: " + end_result[iq].ToString().ToLower() + " s:" + ZENOX_LANGUAGE.Keys.ElementAt(i));
               Console.WriteLine("end translated result: " + end_result);
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RyanWilson its very weird lol- here: https://pastebin.pl/view/1801bd19

Comment: I had to look this up, but I thought I remembered that a `Dictionary` will not always return the value pairs in the order in which they are stored due to it using a hash, you can use an `OrderedDictionary` or a `List<T>` of `KeyValuePair` or call `Enumerable.OrderBy` on the `Dictionary` if you need a precise order. You can read more on this related post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998185/iterating-over-dictionary-with-foreach-in-what-order-is-this-done#:~:text=Dictionary%20s%20are%20hash%20tables,if%20that's%20what%20you%20need.)

Comment: Flip the loops inner/outer, then lookup `ZENOX_LANGUAGE[iq]`. And don't use `ToLower()`, use `Equals()` with `StringComparison`

Comment: @RyanWilson the dictionary is not the problem from what i know- its the splitting up of the ```end_result``` and spitting it into the console.

Comment: @deadgunner Are you sure? Have you stepped through the iteration of the `Dictionary` and ensure that it is returning each item in order? You can also just iterate your string with a traditional `for` loop as a string is an array of `char`

Comment: @RyanWilson here is a console output when i typed "test":
```e

end translated result: test

s

end translated result: test
t
end translated result: test

t

``` **it spells out "estt"**
**the dictionary is using "estt" instead of "test" and therefore is giving the wrong dictionary output- but if it was "test" the dictionary would be correct**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, the order of keys in your dictionary will influence the order that output appears, because you're doing:

```
foreach(var k in dictionary.Keys)
  foreach(char c in someString)
    if(c == k) 
      Console.Write(c)
```

And dictionary keys have no defined order.

Swapping the loops over will mean (as long as the dictionary has the key you're looking for, as it's a condition that leads to printing the char) that the output will appear in order of chars in the string..

..but I can't actually work out why you enumerate the keys and then run a loop looking for the character. I'd just loop over the string and use the char to index the dictionary if I was building some sort of translator map:

```
var map = new Dictionary<char, char>() {
  { 'h', 'Z' }, 
  { 'e', 'Y' }, 
  { 'l', 'X' }, 
  { 'o', 'W' } 
};

var toTrans = "hello";
foreach(char c in toTrans)
  Console.Write(map[c]);
```

This will print "ZYXXW" for an input of "hello";

If you're mapping chars to strings, with case insensitivity it's as simple as:

```
var map = new Dictionary<char, string>() {
  { 'h', "Z0" }, 
  { 'e', "Y0" }, 
  { 'l', "X0" }, 
  { 'o', "W0" } 
};

var toTrans = "HelLO";
foreach(char c in toTrans)
  Console.Write(map[Char.ToLower(c)]);
```

This will print "Z0Y0X0X0W0"

Comment: my program needs that second for loop to get the KEY at that index and the VALUE at that index. i think ive tried out your method by changing one line here: ```end_translated_result += ZENOX_LANGUAGE[iq.ToString()] + " ";``` **where you said** ```Console.write(map[c])```. the output spelt I N P T U - still with one jumbled up.**The dictionary would be correct if the chars that were being split are in correct order**.  please tell me if ive done your answer wrong as ive been coding alot today.

Comment: now ive done some changes and found that 

```char[] end_charArray = end_result.ToCharArray();```

 helped to some degree when i used it here: 

```for(int iq = 0; iq < end_charArray.ToString().Length; iq++)``` but instead the var ```iq``` is only increasing by 1 every 4 runs. like here :

```"0"0"0"0"1"1"1"1"2"2"``` etc

ive also replaced all references of ```end_result``` to ```end_charArray``` like here: 


```end_translated_result += ZENOX_LANGUAGE[end_charArray[iq].ToString().ToUpper()] + " ";```

Comment: You can't turn a char array into a string by calling ToString() on it. The result of `end_charArray.ToString()` is `"System.Char[]"` i.e. the type of the object, not the contents of the array. I think you might need to stop coding, take a step back and think about what youre hoping to achieve

Comment: got it to work but it is a bad way of working- ```foreach (char c in end_charArray)
                {
                    if (counter < end_result.Length)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        end_translated_result += ZENOX_LANGUAGE[c.ToString().ToUpper()] + " ";
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                        Console.WriteLine("end translated result: " + end_translated_result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }```

Comment: *"The output spelt INPTU"* - not possible for an input string of "hello" - there's no way my code would produce an output of all-unique letters if the input has repeated letters. `hello` truly maps to `ZYXXW` like I said it would, look: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KZwSqh

Comment: I can't understand why you have that `counter` variable; `foreach` doesn't "run off the end of" an array so you don't need a separate variable to "make sure you haven't gone past the end of an array", and converting a string to an array with ToCharArray() doesn't produce an array that has a different length than the string

Comment: ""The output spelt INPTU" - not possible for an input string of "hello""- i was referring to me inputting the word "INPUT"- and yes i had a forloop outside of that i removed and it worked finally! thanks to all!